# Azure DevOps React Native iOS build fails when using a scheme build script

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, devops

I'm currently setting up a release pipeline in Azure DevOps for a React Native app. Part of the solution required different config settings for different environments so I've followed the steps in [this](https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-react-native/handling-environment-specific-configurations-in-react-native) article to implement that. One of the steps involves setting up schemes in XCode for the different environments and adding a script to the build step like so:
`cp "{PROJECT_DIR}/../.env.qa" "{PROJECT_DIR}/../.env`
which copies the relevant environment config file. This all works great when deploying locally but when I try to get it working Azure DevOps I encounter this error at the build step:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Run custom shell script 'Run Script'
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

I suspect it's have issues with the PROJECT_DIR part but the error doesn't really tell me much other than it didn't work. Here's the build task from my .yaml file:

```
- task: Xcode@5
    displayName: 'Build IPA'
    inputs:
      actions: 'build'
      configuration: 'Release'
      sdk: 'iphoneos'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/ProjectName.xcworkspace'
      scheme: '$(iOSAppScheme)'
      packageApp: true
      exportPath: 'output'
      signingOption: 'manual'
      signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
      provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```